# Key manipulation not working for datetime type in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime key (all keys infact) to string in a python dictionary (see last line of recursive_items) as below but I am getting non-updated keys in dictionary:

```
def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            yield (key, value)
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        elif type(value) is list:
            yield (key, value)
            for i in value:
                if type(i) is dict:
                    yield from recursive_items(i)
        else:
            
            yield (str(key), value)


item = {'dateCol': {'n': 1000,
  'type': 'Categorical',
  'n': 1000,
  'p': 100.0,
  'n1': 0,
  'p1': 0.0,
  'val': datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0),
  'value_counts': {datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0): 1,
   datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 2, 0, 0): 1,
   datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 11, 0, 0): 1}}} 
            
res = dict()
for key, value in recursive_items(item):
    print(key, type(key))
    res[key]= value
```

When I print key I am getting string as type but in dictionary named 'res' I am still getting datetime. Can someone please guide here?
Thanks.

Edited:
I am getting the output also but dictionary is not the same, is there a way to retain original nested dictionary?

Comment: When I try your code I get `'2000-10-01 00:00:00': 1, '2000-10-02 00:00:00': 1, '2000-10-11 00:00:00': 1` in the resulting dictionary.

Comment: I thought it was obvious still I have edited it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You _do_ get your datetimes converted to strings.  You also get the originals because you `yield key, value` before you `yield from` the recursive call

Comment: Please check screenshot for reference.

Comment: No screenshots of text please. Post the text as text and format it like code

Comment: works as expected for me as well, however, consider using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) for type checks.

Comment: Is there a way to retain original nested dictionary as well?